# What does Return<void> mean?

Tags: c++

I saw a program in android source code ,it's about the return value in c++,please look the following ,Thanks!

```
Return<void> RadioResponse_v1_1::getIccCardStatusResponse(const RadioResponseInfo& info,
                                         const CardStatus& card_status) {
       rspInfo = info
       cardStatus = card_statu parent_v1_1.notify(info.serial30);
       return void();
}
```

My question is that the Return represent what?I've never seen this program before.
Best Regards

Comment: We haven't seen it before either. So, unfortunately, that means we can't really explain it to you.

Comment: I googled to find what you might be referring to: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/interfaces/+/master/radio/1.1/vts/functional/radio_response.cpp

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to dig through all the layers of code generation of the android source code, but here is some documentation about it:
https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl-cpp/functions

It gets used in code generated from some hardware abstraction layer interface language used by AOSP. From the documentation:

> Return objects store transport error indications as well as a T value (except Return).

...

> Return objects have implicit conversion to and from their T value

So, in this case `Return<T>` is a container that can store a value or an error. This function doesn't return anything when it's successful, so it returns `Result<void>`. In functional programming languages, this is sometimes called an either: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ft13/index.html

EDIT: aha, here it is:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/libhidl/+/refs/heads/master/base/include/hidl/Status.h